# Wordmove pull error "Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)"

Tags: ruby

I have Ruby `1.9.3p484` (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux] and when I'm trying to use [Wordmove](https://github.com/welaika/wordmove), I'm getting following pull error:

```
▬▬ ✓ Pulling Database ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
    local | mysqldump --host=localhost --user=USER --password=PASS wpDB > /var/www/local/wp-content/local-backup-1421774302.sql
   remote | mysqldump --host=localhost --user=USER --password=PASS wpDB > /var/www/site/wp-content/dump.sql
   remote | get: /var/www/site/wp-content/dump.sql /var/www/local/wp-content/dump.sql
   remote | delete: /var/www/site/wp-content/dump.sql
    local | adapt dump
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wordmove-1.2.0/lib/wordmove/sql_adapter.rb:44:in `gsub!': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wordmove-1.2.0/lib/wordmove/sql_adapter.rb:44:in `serialized_replace!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wordmove-1.2.0/lib/wordmove/sql_adapter.rb:36:in `replace_field!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wordmove-1.2.0/lib/wordmove/sql_adapter.rb:25:in `replace_vhost!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wordmove-1.2.0/lib/wordmove/sql_adapter.rb:17:in `adapt!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wordmove-1.2.0/lib/wordmove/deployer/base.rb:182:in `adapt_sql'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wordmove-1.2.0/lib/wordmove/deployer/ssh.rb:35:in `pull_db'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wordmove-1.2.0/lib/wordmove/cli.rb:47:in `block in pull'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wordmove-1.2.0/lib/wordmove/cli.rb:34:in `block in handle_options'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wordmove-1.2.0/lib/wordmove/cli.rb:32:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wordmove-1.2.0/lib/wordmove/cli.rb:32:in `handle_options'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wordmove-1.2.0/lib/wordmove/cli.rb:46:in `pull'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wordmove-1.2.0/bin/wordmove:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/wordmove:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/wordmove:23:in `<main>'
```

Other websites run in the very same environment does not show this error. Does anyone have any idea, what can be casuing this error?

Comment: @trejder, @DarkMouse, Thank you for fixing to correct sentence!  
I check `wp-content/dump.sql` ,    
    $ nkf -g  dump.sql   
    UTF-8  
Is this correct?

Comment: Once, I use this command, store data in database.  
`mysql -u USER -pPASS DB < wp-content/dump.sql.  `  
But , I would like to realize using Wordmove...

Comment: @technuma Sorry, I can't help. I don't know nothing about Wordmove or Ruby. I just edited your question, so it looks more like standard here and by this could get better chance being answered (poor quality questions are less frequent answered). But, I can't provide any technical help here.

Comment: @trejder OK, Thank you! I really appreciate what you've done.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/welaika/wordmove/wiki/invalid-byte-sequence-in-UTF-8-(ArgumentError)-with-wordmove-init) a solution and [here](https://github.com/welaika/wordmove/wiki/invalid-byte-sequence-in-UTF-8-while-pushing---pulling-db) a discussion and implementation decision

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
sql_content.encode!('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', :invalid => :replace, :replace => '')
sql_content.encode!('UTF-8', 'UTF-16')
sql_content.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

to this File,above the line 45

```
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/wordmove-2.1.2/lib/wordmove/sql_adapter/default.rb
```

or this File

```
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/wordmove-5.2.2/lib/wordmove/sql_adapter/default.rb
```

Ref: https://github.com/welaika/wordmove/wiki/invalid-byte-sequence-in-UTF-8-while-pushing---pulling-db